# How to change my NavMenu after user Login?

Tags: c#, html, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

**Hello I am stuck on this problem today.**

I have a web interface where you can log in.

**See picture:**
[image: login view]

On the left side I have my navmenu with the different choices.
After the user has logged in I want the navmenu to change and show other menu items (change password, change email).

The problem is that with blazor the navmenu is always applied to all pages.

**Here is my NavMenu.razor**

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
<nav class="flex-column">
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
        </NavLink>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="login">
            <span class="oi oi-account-login" aria-hidden="true"></span> Login
        </NavLink>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="register">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registrieren
        </NavLink>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
            <span class="oi oi-check" aria-hidden="true"></span> Email Prüfen
        </NavLink>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
            <span class="oi oi-question-mark" aria-hidden="true"></span> Passwort Vergessen
        </NavLink>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**How do I make it so that my page gets its own navmenu after login and the existing one does not change?**

Here is my html part of my login page

```
<html>
<h1 class="title">Login</h1>
<br/>
<div class="row px-3">
    <RadzenCard class="card">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3" style="">
                <h3 style="margin-top:3%; margin-left:30px;">Benutzername</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value=@_username class="email_input"></RadzenTextBox>
                <p hidden=@errorMessagesEmail.NoSyntaxError class="errorMail">Ungültige Email Adresse</p>
                <p hidden=@errorMessagesEmail.NoEmptyEmail class="errorMail">Bitte Email Adresse eingeben</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <h3 style="margin-top:3%; margin-left:30px; ">Passwort</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <RadzenPassword  @bind-Value=@_password class="password_input"></RadzenPassword>
                <p hidden=@errorMessagesPassword.NoEmptyPassword class="passwordMessage">Bitte Passwort eingeben</p>
                <p hidden=@errorMessagesPassword.RightCredentials class="passwordMessage">Benutzername oder Passwort falsch</p>
                <p hidden=@errorMessagesPassword.NotToManyRequest  class="passwordMessage">Zu viele Anfragen mit einem falschen Passwort</p>
                <br/>
                 <p class="errorMail">@_loginErrorMessages</p>
                <p hidden=@_logInFailed class="passwordMessage">Erfolgreich</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </RadzenCard>
    <RadzenButton Click=@OnLogin class="rz-button" ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Text="Login"></RadzenButton>
</div>
```

Thanks for all Answers
If you need any more infos just let me Know
;P

Answer (score 2):

You use `<AuthorizeView>` to display differing content depending on the user's authorization status. This is called authorization.

- For authenticated users, you can display content specific to them inside the `<Authorized>`.
- If user is not logged in and you want to show content only of unathorized users, place the content inside `<NotAuthorized>` element.

To enable authorization in your pages you need to enable authentication state in `App.razor`

**App.razor:**

```razor
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Then you need to update your NavMenu to show links accordingly, for example when a user is not logged in, show the login and registration menu but not email or password menu because those last 2 menus I assume are for authenticated users only.

**NavMenu.razor**

```razor
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">BlazorApp1</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="login">
                        <span class="oi oi-account-login" aria-hidden="true"></span> Login
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="register">
                        <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registrieren
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                        <span class="oi oi-check" aria-hidden="true"></span> Email Prüfen
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                        <span class="oi oi-question-mark" aria-hidden="true"></span> Passwort Vergessen
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
            </Authorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: Authorization in nav menu links]

Comment: This makes sense to me but how doese the programm know that im logged in or out?

Comment: @obind The program will know by using `<AuthorizeView>` as it will display differing content depending on the user's authorization status. This is called authorization. For logged in users whatever is inside <Authorized> element will be shown to them, but if user is not logged in you might want to show a different content inside `<NotAuthorized>` element

Comment: mhh i dont know... are you using the razor login component? i build my login on my own how can i tell the program that the login was succsesssfull and the user is now Authorized?

Comment: @obind I believe you are using custom authentication that is not `ASP.NET Core Identity`. Custom authentication is tedious to work with because you have to do everything by yourself. There is no need to reinvent the wheel. For information how to install ASP.NET Core Identity check out an example at https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2022/01/dotnet6-implementing-aspnetcore-identity-authentication-in-to-an-existing-blazor-server-app.html

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `AuthorizeView` Component. For details see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Basically you can have `NavMenu.razor` like this:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <AuthorizedMenu />
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <NotAuthorizedMenu />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

with your current code being moved to the new `NotAuthorizedMenu.razor` component.

*This should work, but I'm not at my VS atm to test it fully. So some changes might be needed.*

**Please note (from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)):**

> The AuthorizeView component can be used in the NavMenu component (Shared/NavMenu.razor) to display a NavLink component (NavLink), but note that this approach only removes the list item from the rendered output. It doesn't prevent the user from navigating to the component.